# $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)=\mathbb{Q}(\lambda\sqrt2 + \mu\sqrt3)$

Tags: field-theory

I am trying to prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)=\mathbb{Q}(\lambda\sqrt2+ \mu\sqrt3)$ for all $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{Q}*$. I understand that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)$, but I am not sure what to do with the $\lambda, \mu$ .

Comment: That deals with $\lambda=\mu=1$. Infinitely more choices to go! Does your proof for $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$ also work for $\lambda\sqrt2+\mu\sqrt3$?

Comment: I don't think so, I proved that by looking at $(\sqrt2 + \sqrt3)^{-1}$. By doing the same for $\lambda\sqrt2 + \mu\sqrt3$ I'm not sure how to proceed after getting the fraction $\frac{\lambda\sqrt2-\mu\sqrt3}{2\lambda^2-3\mu^2}$.

Comment: Try computing the degree $[\mathbb{Q}(\lambda \sqrt{2} + \mu\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}]$. Show that $4$ divides the degree, and show that it must be $\leq 4$. This tells you that the degree is equal to 4, which is what you need.

Comment: Could you tell me how I am supposed to do that? I see that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt3, \sqrt2):\mathbb{Q}]=4$ which gives us a basis with $\{1, \sqrt2, \sqrt3, \sqrt6\}$. But I dont know how to find a minimum polynomial for $\lambda \sqrt2 + \mu \sqrt3$ since these variables are unknown.

Comment: Please say more about your background. This becomes trivial if you have done Galois correspondence for then you know that the ONLY intermediate fields are $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt n)$ with $n=2,3$ or $6$. $\lambda\sqrt{2}+\mu\sqrt{3}$ isn't in any of them, so we can conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lambda,\mu\in\Bbb{Q}^{\times}$ and let $\alpha:=\lambda\sqrt{2}+\mu\sqrt{3}$. Then $\alpha\in\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ so the degree $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha):\Bbb{Q}]$ divides $[\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}):\Bbb{Q}]=4$. If $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha):\Bbb{Q}]\neq4$ then there exist $u,v\in\Bbb{Q}$ such that
$$\alpha^2+u\alpha+v=0,\tag{1}$$
where
$$\alpha^2=2\lambda^2+3\mu^2+2\lambda\mu\sqrt{6}.$$
Then comparing the coefficients of $\sqrt{6}$ in $(1)$ shows that $\lambda\mu=0$, a contradiction.

This shows that $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha):\Bbb{Q}]=4$ and hence that $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$.